# POST to page and return in text

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Below I have a function to grab the echo of a php page. Note: this echo is usually just a color (Green, Blue, ect...). I want to be able to POST to that php page and still return a text only which I can apply to the variable $test.

Basically, in short I want to be able to do the same thing as below, but also POST a variable to the php page.

```
$(function(){
   var test = "";
   function loadData() {  
      $.get("roomdata.php", function(test) {
         alert(test);
         setTimeout(loadData, 10000);
      }, 'text'); 
   }
   loadData();
});
```

Thanks! - Been trying to figure this out forever.

Note: I posted something similar yesterday, but this one is probably clearer and a step ahead.

Comment: I believe you should look into the $.ajax function

Comment: maybe... just maybe... `$.post()`  might be a good starting point...

Comment: @Hogan: I have, but the ajax function only allows for one type at a time:  type: 'get',  Unless there's another way of doing it.

Comment: @Gosre - See answers, you can use type = post in `$.ajax()` (yay `$.ajax()`

Comment: @Gosre  your answers are all in examples in the jQuery API

Comment: @Hogan: Yeah! Guess what I was trying to get was the .done(function(msg) which was posted below by wumm. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an ajax call with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "process.php",
 data: {
   abc: 'string' //send this to the php script
 },
cache: false
}).done(function(msg) {
 alert(msg); //alert what the php script says
}
```

Comment: can also use shortcut method `$.post()`

Answer (score 1):

See [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Use it like this :

```
$.post('roomdata.php',
    { varname: 'data' }, // varname is whatever variable name expected in POST
    function(response) {
        var return_value = data; // that's the data returned.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [check the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (always check the documentation!) then you would find that this would work:

```
$.get('page.php',
      { variable: 'someVar' },
      function(data) {
      ...
});
```

> jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )

Comment: when the page is requested asynchronously, it is sent with the parameter {variable: 'someVar'}, hence the PHP page is receiving the parameter (he wanted the same thing as he had in his question, but while sending a parameter to the php page)

Answer (score 0):

Include this :) Good Luck ..

```
 var request =$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "HANDLEPOST.php",
        data: { testvar : test } });
        request.done(function(msg) {
          $("#out").html("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
        });
```